# Reliable method to check internet connection in C++ application: gethostbyname() failing

Tags: c++, windows, networking

I am developing a C++ network application on Windows. I need to check if internet connection is there or not. I am using `gethostbyname()`, but it is giving incorrect information when the system is connected through a proxy. `InternetCheckConnection()` and `InternetGetConnectedState()` are also not giving reliable results under different conditions. Is there a reliable way to check for internet connectivity covering all the conditions such as proxy and VPN?

**Update:**

In our company network `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl()` is failing with the error `ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED` and `WinHttpSendrequest()` is failing with error `ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

In open network `WinHttpSendrequest()` is successful.

Comment: How are you defining "internet connectivity"?  What incorrect information is gethostbyname() giving you?  I think most LANs do provide DNS service, so normally you would expect it to work, but of course that doesn't mean you can actually contact the host in question.

Comment: Are you using WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration?  Are the system proxy settings correctly defined, e.g., does Internet Explorer work?

Comment: Yes,the system proxy settings are defined correctly and Internet explorer works.

Answer (score 14):

Plain old way !

Include:

```
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Wininet.lib")
```

In your Method:

```
char url[128];
strcat(url, "http://www.techtoolbox.com");
bool bConnect = InternetCheckConnection(url, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0);


if (bConnect)
{
    //internet connection exists !
}
else
{
            //internet DOES NOT connection exists !
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to test the availability of any resource is to try to use it. You only care about the Internet if there is something out there you want to connect to. So, try to connect to it, in the normal course of your program, and handle the errors. Don't try to second-guess what might happen if you try. First, you're trying to predict the future. Second, you aren't necessarily exercising the same things that the actual connection would exercise. Third, your test may succeed and your subsequent use fail due to an intervening condition changing. Fourth, you have to handle the errors from the real use of the resource anyway: why write all that code twice?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to try to connect to a well-known host, if it succeeds then you have a connection.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a way is to create a socket and try connecting a known host. These links will help:
For windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673(VS.85).aspx and for unix http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html.

HTH 
Anil